# Can not use {{}} with phone

Tags: vuejs2, axios

```
var walink = "https://web.whatsapp.com/send",
    phone = "https://4934-175-158-53-206.ap.ngrok.io/api/user/contact",
    walink2 = "Halo saya ingin melakukan pemesanan paket wisata",
    text_yes = "Terkirim.",
    text_no = "Isi semua Formulir lalu klik Send.";
```

```
how to call contacts phone in beck end??
```

Comment: What do you want exactly here?

Comment: PLease explain in detail what you are trying to do and what is not working!